# this / Extend Context?

Tags: android, rest, this, android-volley, android-context

I'm not able to use (this) in this code.  The suggestion I get from IDEA is to extend Context, which I definitely don't want to do.  I've tried importing Context and using (Context context) instead, but no luck.  Why can't I use "this"?

public class LastFMLogin {

```
final String lastFMKeyURL = "http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=" + R.string.lastfm_api_key;
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

public void authGetRequest() {
    // prepare the Auth Get Request
    JsonObjectRequest lastFMAuthRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, lastFMKeyURL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // display response
                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            });

    // add it to the RequestQueue
    queue.add(lastFMAuthRequest);

}
```

}

My Tutorial class calls lastFMAuthRequest, but I get a "cannot resolve context" error.

```
public void lastFMButtonListener() {

    ImageButton lastfm_login = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lastfm_login);
    lastfm_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d(debug, "LastFM Round clicked");
            //Change button image
            ImageButton lastfm_login = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lastfm_login);
            lastfm_login.setImageResource(R.drawable.lastfm_pressed);
            LastFMLogin lastFMLogin = new LastFMLogin();
            lastFMLogin.lastFMAuthRequest(Context context);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "this" in Service or Activity. etc., but not in custom class. Because "this" in custom(not extended) class not equal Context. Use satti code to provide context to your class.

---

Or provide context only to method:

```
final String lastFMKeyURL = "http://www.last.fm/api/auth/?api_key=" +  R.string.lastfm_api_key;
RequestQueue queue = null;

 public void authGetRequest(Context context) {

 queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

// prepare the Auth Get Request
JsonObjectRequest lastFMAuthRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, lastFMKeyURL, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // display response
                Log.d("Response", response.toString());
            }
        },

        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
            }
        });

// add it to the RequestQueue
queue.add(lastFMAuthRequest);

}
```

---

Usage of default constructor is good when you use Context in many methods and don't want to add Context param in each method when you call it.
For example:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this); // Called ones
```

and then just use:

```
myClass.method1();
myClass.method2();
myClass.method3();
myClass.method4();
```

etc.

Each method uses Context wich you provide in default constructor.

Also you can use not only "this".

```
getApplicationContext()
getBaseContext()
```

Differences explained in docs.

Enjoy! )

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  That works better, as I didn't need a new constructor, but I definitely needed to call the lastFMAuthRequest method from another class in my app.  Thx for explaining!

Comment: That works, but when I try to call lastFMAuthRequest from another class, I get a "can not resolve context" error.

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    LastFMLogin lastFMLogin = new LastFMLogin();
    lastFMLogin.lastFMAuthGetRequest(Context context);
}
});

Comment: another class extends Activity? Edit your question and past code from another class. Also, I edit my answer.

Comment: But it's possible to use Context in only 1 method, correct?  So why couldn't I use this on the method before?  (Question edited).

Comment: @darkMatter, lastFMLogin.lastFMAuthRequest(Tutorial.this);

Comment: Man, I gotta read up on this & context.  Confusing, but problem solved!  Thx!

Comment: You are welcome. If you just call "this" in your code it's will refer to OnClickListener. It's why you need use "ClassName.this".

Comment: @darkMatter, you can use Context as many methods as you want.

Comment: Oh, so you use ClassName.this to get out of the current method you're in?

Comment: I used it to clarify what "this" I need

Answer (score 1):

Create one constructor, which will accept the Context, and use it where ever you want.

Ex:

```
public class LastFMLogin {
    private Context mContext;

    public LastFMLogin(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Woot!  That definitely got rid of the error.  But I'm not quite sure I understand the logic behind it.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: `Volley.newRequestQueue()` requires a `Context` as a parameter (an Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver or Service). If you pass an `Activity` `Context` around, make *SURE* whatever object is holding that reference is released on or before that `Activity` instance is destroyed or you'll end up with a memory leak. Alternatively, if you're not starting other activities or inflating views, you can store the application context (activity.getApplicationContext()) safely.

Comment: What do you mean by "make SURE whatever object is holding that reference is released?"

Comment: @darkMatter For example, if you were keeping a reference to that object (which is keeping a reference to your activity) as a static variable somewhere (or in a long-running service, asynctask, etc.), you have to release the activity reference (just set the reference to null) otherwise the activity cannot be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Cause in the case, 'this' refer to the Anonymous#InnerClass created as param to the method (the interface implementation).

You can refer the outer class with FullName.this

public void lastFMButtonListener() {

```
ImageButton lastfm_login = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lastfm_login);
lastfm_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.d(debug, "LastFM Round clicked");
        //Change button image
        ImageButton lastfm_login = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lastfm_login);
        lastfm_login.setImageResource(R.drawable.lastfm_pressed);
        LastFMLogin lastFMLogin = new LastFMLogin();
        lastFMLogin.lastFMAuthRequest(MyClass.this);
    }
});
```

}